# How to explain commutativity between divisors and between divisor and multipliers

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic

dividend is non-commutative:

```
        8÷2=4       ≠   2÷8=1/4
        8÷2÷2=2     ≠   2÷8÷2=1/8
```

divisors are commutative. multipliers are also commutative with divisor

```
        8÷2÷4=1     =   8÷4÷2=1
        50÷5x3=30   =   50x3÷5=30
```

how to explain that?

Comment: Writing iterated divisions without parentheses is ambiguous.  $(8\div 2)\div 4= 4\div 4=1$ but $8\div (2\div 4)=8\div \frac 12=16$.  If you always mean the former then $(a\div b)\div c=a\div (b\times c)=(a\div c)\div b$.

Comment: @lulu: I think natural order of operatin (from left to right) implies the first case. your explanation sounds logical. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first:
$$
a \div b \div c = a \div (b\cdot c) = a \div (c\cdot b) = a \div c \div b
$$
This may be easier to see when using fraction notation:

$$
a \div b \div c = a \cdot \frac{1}{b} \cdot \frac{1}{c} = \frac{a}{bc} = \frac{a}{cb} = a \div c \div b
$$

On a slightly more technical level, this is a consequence of the fact that when we say $a \div b$ we mean $ab^{-1}$, understood as "$a$ times the multiplicative inverse of $b$." Similarly, $a \div b \div c$ means $ab^{-1}c^{-1}$. But it turns out that $b^{-1}c^{-1} = (cb)^{-1}$, so we get that $a \div b \div c = a \div (c\cdot b)$.

Comment: Good answer. I see the fraction notation and the inverse notation are applicable to  50÷5x3=30   =   50x3÷5=30 scenario. thanks